# How to use React.memo with react-redux connect and set propsAreEqual?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, memo

I'm using `react-redux` and I have a component connected to it.
my component has its own props (variants and functions) and also some state from store mapped with it, using `mapStateToProps`.

It's very important to us to manage when this component should re-render and for this purpose we're using `propsAreEqual` as a second argument to React.memo.

```
...

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
  name: state.user.name,
});

const dispatchProps = {
  editProfile: userActions.editProfile,
};

interface IProps {
  isOnCompleteProfile: boolean;
  onClickMessage: () => void;
}
type Props = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> & typeof dispatchProps & IProps;

const MyFunction: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {

   ...

}

function propsAreEqual(prevProps: IProps, nextProps: IProps) {
  return prevProps.isOnCompleteProfile === nextProps.isOnCompleteProfile;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatchProps)(React.memo(MyFunction, propsAreEqual));
```

My question is, will this component re-render after `state.user.name` change in this scenario? or i have to mention `prevProps.name === nextProps.name;` in `propsAreEqual` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Connect` essentially wraps your component in a separate component (HOC) and renders your memoized component given the props from the `mapStateToProps` function.

That being said, your memoized component will receive a prop called `name`. So you will have to return false in the `propsAreEqual` function in order for the component to update.

Answer (score 1):

The component won't re-render even after `state.user.name` change.

Because you're memoizing the function `MyFunction` based on your isOnCompleteProfile `props`.
When isOnCompleteProfile changes, your function re-renders.